# Problem with the cart menu on the safari browser

Tags: menu, overflow, shopping-cart

I have a problem with cart on safari browser. The problem is that when i add multiple products to the cart on safari browser i get overflow but on every other browser i get the product one under another.

https://prnt.sc/G-EIvdARiDjU this is the example for the classic browser

https://prnt.sc/Zs6ENzRCGPCh this is on safari

i found one solution with min-height 100% but when i do that the menu is using 100% of the right side although it doesn't need that much space. I tried with min-content too but when i do that the items from menu just disapear..